# How do I create an Oracle table of objects containing nested tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, user-defined-types

My question is similar to  [9454933](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454933)  but my nested table is within the object.

I wish to create a table of user defined types where the defined type contains an object, my simplified setup looks like this

```
CREATE TYPE DEMO_TYPE1 AS OBJECT (A1 NUMBER, A2 NUMBER);

CREATE TYPE DEMO_TAB_TYPE1 AS TABLE OF DEMO_TYPE1;

CREATE TYPE DEMO_TYPE2 AS OBJECT (B1 NUMBER, B2 DEMO_TAB_TYPE1);

CREATE TABLE DEMO_TAB1 (C1 NUMBER, C2 DEMO_TYPE2);
```

If I run the above I get the following error

```
The storage clause is not specified for the nested table column or attribute.
```

This makes sense but I can't work out the correct syntax to fix this I've tried

```
CREATE TABLE DEMO_TAB1 (C1 NUMBER, C2 DEMO_TYPE2)
NESTED TABLE B2 STORE AS B2_TAB;
```

but this and every other variation I've tried result in 
    ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

So how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the error is that the C2 is not a nested table. The nested table is the B2 inside C2, so you should try this:

```
CREATE TABLE DEMO_TAB1 (C1 NUMBER, C2 DEMO_TYPE2)
NESTED TABLE C2.B2 STORE AS B2_TAB;
```

See sqlfiddle:  [sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c662/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c662/1)

Comment: I did try that as a solution but still get the same missing or invalid option.

Comment: I have checked it before posting, it works. See sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c662/1, pls.

Comment: Sorry you were correct I had an additional typo in my SQL.  Thanks for the answer and for the link to sqlfiddle it's a nice resource I'll try and remember it.