# Unable to create a table with a column of object type (and the same object type contains an attribute of nested table type)

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I am trying to create a table with a column of object type and tricky nested table hierarchy. Getting ORA-22913 error. In CREATE table statement the column "theCol" is of type object (i.e. MainObj). MainObj contains an attribute of type nested table i.e. ChildTab.
I think am supposed to use NESTED TABLE clause in CREATE TABLE statement. But not sure how to use it here because "theCol" is NOT of nested table type.

```
DROP TYPE MainObj;
DROP TYPE ChildTab;
DROP TYPE ChildObj;

CREATE TYPE ChildObj AS OBJECT (
naame varchar2(20)
, kaam varchar2(20)
);
/

CREATE TYPE ChildTab AS TABLE OF ChildObj;
/

Create TYPE MainObj as OBJECT (
    KEEY VARCHAR2(5),
    ChildList  ChildTab
);
/

CREATE TABLE TestTableDesi (
 theCol MainObj
);
/
```

Type dropped.
Type dropped.
Type dropped.
Type created.
Type created.
Type created.
ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create an Oracle table with nested tables of object types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454933/how-do-i-create-an-oracle-table-with-nested-tables-of-object-types)

Comment: This problem is slightly different as the attribute in CREATE TABLE statement is of type object.. not a type of nested table

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution here. [How do I create an Oracle table of objects containing nested tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012019/how-do-i-create-an-oracle-table-of-objects-containing-nested-tables?rq=1)
The create table statement should be as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTableDesi (
theCol MainObj
) nested table theCol.ChildList store as ChildList_tab ;
/
```